# I don't find anymore my tablet(Polaroid MIDC 901) in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, tablet

Yesterday I was using my tablet ( Polaroid MIDC 901) to debug my application and this night I found some update on SDK and I did it and then I don't find it anymore (when I run on eclipse and also on adb it shows me error device not found) if anyone have already seen this and can help it will be great thank you (the driver is already installed so I don't know where is the problem, and debug USB checked).

Comment: in either the terminal or command prompt, can you run "adb devices" to get a list of connected devices. To do this you need adb in your path or you can run it from <your-android-sdk-location>/platform-tools/

Comment: Just in case: but check if You have installed drivers for Your device.

Comment: @adityajones i do this in the folder using the command (CTRL + SHIFT Right bouton open commande here )

Comment: @krzakov yes i have already installed i have adb composite in my device manager

Comment: @ClubberBen I'm not sure what you mean. Did you run the command? or is this the way that you open up your Terminal/Command Prompt? If you ran the command, do you have any output? What OS are you using (if you need help)?

Comment: @adityajones i open a command prompt when i m in the file (where my adb Android Tools by using the shortcul (CTRL + SHIT RIGHT BOUTON CLIC ) and i run the commands adb kill-server 
and adb start-server
adb usb or adb devices it returns error device not found 
i m using windows 7

Comment: @adityajones i have found the problem with updates my file adb_usb.in was empty and normally i must have un exa number to recognize my tablet and the oode i add into the file is 0x2207 and everything is working now thank you !